# Calling .net4 from SSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, ssis

We've done some work on a .net 4.0 project, and are now looing into using SSIS for some tasks. As SSIS is not supported in VS2010, as far as I can see, I'm sort of ok with using VS2008 for SSIS. But how can I call exsiting .net4 code from SSIS at best running on .net 3.5?

Do I have to wrap my c# code to a web service or are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of .NET for an application depends on the main executable. If you use DTEXEC to run SSIS, you get .NET 3.5 because DTEXEC.Exe is configured to use .NET 3.5.

But if you build your own application (a simple console app with functionality similar to DTEXEC) with .NET 4.0 - you get .NET 4.0.

Finally, there is of course a hack to change DTEXEC to use .NET 4.0 - it is controlled by DTEXEC.Exe.Config, which you can edit, but most likely this is unsupported by Microsoft and thus I would recommend against it.